# Convert click for static pages in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've setup this structure in my Ionic v1 app.
This is for contents and load more effect.

```
$scope.toggleItem= function(item) {
            if ($scope.isItemShown(item)) {
                $scope.shownItem = null;
            } else {
                $scope.shownItem = item;

            }
        };
        $scope.isItemShown = function(item) {
            return $scope.shownItem === item;
        };
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz)

But now I need another solution. I have a static content in the page so I should change this toggle method.

[AFTER RESULT](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqOgbq)

I tried that but its not working. Whats the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly suggest not using Ionic version 1 if you are starting a new project today. The current release of Ionic is version 3 which is very very different to version 1 and they are dropping support rapidly for older versions.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is a good tip for me. But started with v1 and must continue with this version.

Comment: Check provided answer

Answer (score 0):

In your controller the members to reference are **$scope.toggleGroup** and **$scope.isGroupShown**, but you're calling $scope.toggleItem and $scope.isItemShown.
You can change the controller or view to match each other

Also, you are not using Ionic tags to make it work, you have the static content inside normal Divs!!
Finally, put parameters on the functions you're calling, the controller member function is expecting the "group" parameter:

> ```
>     <ion-item class="item-stable"
>                 ng-click="toggleItem(100)"
>                 ng-class="{active: isItemShown(100)}">
>         <i class="icon" ng-class="isItemShown(100) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
>         İş Sağlığı ve Güvenliği İçin Ne Gibi Önlemler Alabilirim?
>       </ion-item>
>       <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isItemShown(100)">
>         Tarım iş sağlığı ve güvenliği ...
>       </ion-item>
> ```

Note the "100" parameter in the calls to toggleItem(100) and isItemShown(100). It has to be a **unique value per item**, I have pass "100" just as a sample to demonstrate the idea

Working sample:
https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/Ljaymd?editors=1010

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me problem on codepen? Thanks.

Comment: Look at this one and check if it works as you expect: https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/Ljaymd

Comment: Let me quickly check, It was not clear for me what was the static content you were refering to. It was not working at any content on my first review

Comment: A new edit on CodePen: https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/Ljaymd?editors=1010. You can see it works with static content. The trick is to assign constant values to the "group" parameter, ensure these values are unique tho. And yes, if you want it to work with ionic, put inside ionic tags!!!!

Comment: Please check new comments an updated answer to help more if needed